# Vertical CJK text on an R plot

Tags: r, cjk, vertical-text

Is there any convenient way to get vertical CJK text onto an R plot? Both as labels for points/polygons, and just as part of a block of arbitrary text placed on the plot.

The one potential method I've found so far is to use the `ragg` package to pass something like the `vrt2` OpenType feature to a font so that it uses one of those glyph sets meant for writing vertical text in a horizontal environment, and then rotating it to be correct. Is there an easier way to do it than that?

Answer (score 0):

Simply putting newlines between the characters might be enough.  For example,

```
plot(1,1)
text(1,1, adj = -1, labels="日\n本", family = "Arial Unicode MS")
```

produces this:
[image: screenshot]

Doing a block of text is more tedious:  I think each line
will need to be drawn separately.  For example,

```
plot(1,1, type="n")
text(1,1.2, adj = c(-1,1), labels="古\n池\nや", family = "Arial Unicode MS")
text(1,1.2, adj = c(0,1), labels="蛙\n飛\nび\n込\nむ", family = "Arial Unicode MS")
text(1,1.2, adj = c(1,1), labels="水\nの\n音", family = "Arial Unicode MS")
```

produces this:

[image: screenshot]

Edited to add:  If the character spacing is unacceptable, you can use the `par("lheight")` parameter to adjust it.  For example,

```
plot(1,1, type="n")
par(lheight = 0.8)
text(1,1.2, adj = c(-1,1), labels="古\n池\nや", family = "Arial Unicode MS")
text(1,1.2, adj = c(0,1), labels="蛙\n飛\nび\n込\nむ", family = "Arial Unicode MS")
text(1,1.2, adj = c(1,1), labels="水\nの\n音", family = "Arial Unicode MS")
```

which gives

[image: screenshot]

It's fairly easy to automate the insertion of newlines, but I'll leave that to you.  What would be hard would be to have variable spacing, e.g to insert small spaces or parentheses.

Comment: Seems like a last-ditch solution, especially if I'm trying to import labels from a data set. Plus, the character spacing is off, since the inter-line spacing is larger than the inter-character spacing. It could be made to work if all else fails, but I certainly hope there's a better solution!

Comment: @Sjiveru, you should post an example of what you want or a link to an image of it.

Comment: For example, if I wanted to reproduce something like this map - https://stat.ameba.jp/user_images/20140815/05/edo-sanpo/71/03/j/o0750043113035007388.jpg?caw=800. (that's not exactly what I want, but it would enable me to do what I want)

Comment: I see your edits, and that does make it at least better, but your mention of parentheses makes me remember that a number of characters (including （）、。ー) have alternate rotated forms when vertical and just plain adding newlines won't work for them at all. If I don't happen to have any of those, your solution will work (though it's still clunky), but I'll hold out for a more elegant solution that handles all aspects of vertical text properly.